# camel route with regex choice

Tags: regex, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am new to servicemix/camel and not the greatest at regex but any help would be grateful.

I have a route which splits a file and converts each line into a class via bindy. This works fine. However, i only want lines which match a regex.

Using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ i've checked my regex matches the test data, but when i run the route, all lines go to "Didnt match regex".

```
<split>
<tokenize token="\n"/>
<choice>
    <when>
        <!-- Regex: Matches on A, U or D followed by pipe | then ANYTHING, i.e.: A|azz454... -->
        <simple>${body} regex '^[AUD]\|.*'</simple>
        <unmarshal ref="bindyMasterProduct" />
        <log message="OUTPUT: ${body}"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
           <log message="Didnt match regex: ${body}"/>
       </otherwise>
</choice>
</split>
```

Regex:

```
^[AUD]\|.*
```

Match:

```
A|AZZ709256|Cheryl
```

DONT-Match:

```
Mode|Ref|Name
```

Comment: I've also tried: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html which gives the expected results, so i am 99% sure the regex is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised i was going about the problem the wrong way. I dont need to to split the file at line level, i can just let bindy do it all for me.

I added the "skipFirstLine" annotation to my class and replaced the whole of the split xml with:

```
<unmarshal ref="bindyMasterProduct" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct, but you need to escape the backslash, like `'^[AUD]\\|.*'`.